# GAPI integration between frontend and backend

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I have a single page application with some user-related calendars. The task is to write integration with the google calendar. A user should be able to click on 'integrate with google calendar', select his google account, give read+write access to the calendar, and then the application should be able to do a number of things within the user google calendar like creating a new calendar and sync all events inside it with the application data.

I started with this example, https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js

It works, but as I understand it's for online front end work only. Is it possible to retrieve authentication from this front end and send it to the back end? I want back end to operate server-to-server mode, while the user is offline.

I have checked the other, back end gapi integrations, but they do not look so cool, there're some redirects. I want to keep everything inside a single page with ajax and popups.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a users data when the user is off line you need something called [offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline).   When you authecate the user you will need to request offline access then the server will return to you a refresh token.

A refresh token is long lived you will be able to use your refresh token at anytime to request a new access token which will allow you to access the users data.

*You cant use offline access with JavaScript you will need to use a server sided language like say node.js, php, phython .... you will not be able to use gapi*